Wifi card rtw89 8851BE not detected by Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS Jammy Jellyfish
##Please see output at this link https://termbin.com/nru6.
I have looked at https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89 and tried it but it doesn't work. It also says this in the description.
"This code will build on any kernel 6.10 and newer as long as the distro has not modified any of the kernel APIs. IF YOU RUN UBUNTU, YOU CAN BE ASSURED THAT THE APIs HAVE CHANGED. NO, I WILL NOT MODIFY THE SOURCE FOR YOU. YOU ARE ON YOUR OWN!!!!!"
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit the post to include the wireless script results

Updated with the outputs from the link above.

In terminal try echo "blacklist rtw89_core"|sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtw89_core.conf and reboot

@jeremy31 done that and reboot. Still not working. Terminal output: blacklist rtw89_core.
Updated output here: https://termbin.com/i424

Can you double click on the deb file you made from the lwfinger github and uninstall?  Then in terminal sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtw89_core.conf then reboot and see if it works?

When I open the deb file, there is only a binary and 2 tar files inside. Nothing along the lines of uninstall.

Doesn't it run in Software Manager?

Oh yes, I opened it with software manager and uninstalled. Rebooted and now Wifi works!!! thanks for your help!

@jeremy31 I restarted my computer and the Wifi doesn't work again. I checked the deb file, its still uninstalled. I tried running sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtw89_core.conf as well but it did not work.

In terminal wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info enter your password when prompted and press y when asked to upload results, post URL from terminal here

@Jeremy31 https://termbin.com/bkq5 here are the results

Power off, remove power cord and battery(if simple), then press and hold power button for 30 seconds.  Put it back together and boot

@Jeremy31 Thanks, that fixed it. Any ideas why?

Something got messed up in the BIOS, the script results showed an error near the end of failure to probe and that usually means something wrong in BIOS or Windows Hybrid shutdown

@Jeremy31 Thanks for your help!
